# Como puedo ingresar fecha y hora desde java a Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy creando un proyecto de estacionamiento de coches lo estoy haciendo en java y Mysql, en fecha/hora de entrada del coche lo inserto sin problemas, pero el detalle es cuando inserto fecha/hora de salida ya que desde el botón de salida realizo el evento pero me sale error de excepción.

Aquí tengo mi código del evento de acción de botón salida con conexión a la base de dato.

```
 private void btnsalidaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    conectarBD conec = new conectarBD();
    Connection cn = conec.conexion();

      String hora_salida;
      String sql = "";
    try {

        hora_salida = ((JTextField)JDentradaSalida.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();


  sql = "INSERT INTO altavehiculos (hora_salida) VALUES(?)";
         PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);

           pst.setString(1,hora_salida);


         int n = pst.executeUpdate();
           if (n > 0) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se dio salida correctamente");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
     Logger.getLogger(Alta_de_vehiculos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
```

//         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se dio salida correctamente");
        }

```
}
```

Este es el error de excepción que sale.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla de la base de dato.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: marca está como not null, por eso te dice que no tiene un valod por defecto y no puede insertarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si cuando haces la entrada ya tienes ingresado en vehículo en la BD, cuando el vehículo se vá y le haces la salida, tienes que hacer un UPDATE a la BD, no un INSERT porque en ese caso estarías agregando otra fila a la BD, y no estás diciendo qué id de auto ni ninguna de las otros datos. Tu código debería ser:

```
sql = "UPDATE altavehiculos SET hora_salida = ? WHERE idVehiculo = ?";
     PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);

       pst.setString(1,hora_salida);
       pst.setInt(2, idVehiculo);
     int n = pst.executeUpdate();
       if (n > 0) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se dio salida correctamente");

    }
```

Comment: Gracias probare y comento de nuevo.

Comment: Realice lo que me comenta de utilizar el UPDATE, si se me  actualiza pero el problema que también se actualiza la columna de hora de entrada pero esa columna no la tengo para actualizar.

Comment: Gracias amigo Alex lo resolví tal como dijo.

Comment: Por nada, no olvides entonces dar la respuesta como correcta.